# Взгляд со стороны

Tags: html, css, mysql

Здравствуйте, я совсем новичок, требуется создать форму, при заполнении которой значения будут улетать в БД, наведите на путь правильный (литература, мануалы).
З.ы. прошу оценить "корректность" кода, что лишнее, а что требуется добавить (если не сложно).

```css
fieldset {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 75, 0.1);
}
legend {
 font-weight: bold;
}/* CSS Document */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Документ без названия</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<form action="NADO SDELAT.php">
  <div class="bio">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Личная информация:</legend>
      <label>Имя:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" size="30" maxlength="100">
      <label>Фамилия:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" size="30" maxlength="100">
      <label>Телефон для связи:</label>
      <input type="tel" name="tel" size="30" maxlength="100">
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="rules">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Правила посещения:</legend>
      <ol>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
      </ol>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>С правилами ознакомлен.</label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="comments">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Комментарии:</legend>
      <textarea cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label>Нужно чистое постельное белье.</label>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Записаться!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: p.s.s. Я прошу лишь наводку на ответ, а не сам ответ.

Answer (score 0):

> p.s.s. Я прошу лишь наводку на ответ, а не сам ответ. – Alakazama

Внимание! Навожу - [ТЫК](http://addphp.ru/materials/mysql/1_5.php)

Comment: Вдогонку [ТЫК](http://www.php.su/mysql/)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, неплохо.

Я бы, правда, даже для вывода такой простой страницы использовал какой-нибудь "движок". Например, [Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/).

Собственно, на этом же сайте много что тебе может пригодиться в дальнейшем. Тут и [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) и [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp). Возможно тебе пригодится в дальнейшем и [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp).

Так же есть ещё [такой хороший сайтик](http://htmlbook.ru/).

Из твоего кода не понятно какой язык программирования ты будешь использовать для записи в MySQL..
Предполагаю, что самым простым  будет PHP, на который уже дал [ссылку](http://www.php.su/mysql/) @Qwerty_Wasd

Дерзай)

Comment: Я до этого пользовался CMS wp/joomla/OC и что толку? Работать в них умею, а скилл это никак не повышает, вот и решил открыть блокнот и начать все ручками, ручками.

Comment: @Alakazama, ну тогда мой ответ как раз для тебя) Bootstrap это не CMS, а некий набор заготовок для быстрого создания сайта в блокноте. Базовый набор CSS, который можешь поменять по своему вкусу.